# Convert Empty string ("") to Double data type while importing data from JSON file using command line BQ command

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
1.I am running command: 
        ./bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=lifeSchema.json  dataset_test1.table_test_3 lifeData.json
2.I have attached data source file and scema files.
3. It throws an error - JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file:
file-00000000. Could not convert value to double. Field:
computed_results_A; Value:

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
I want empty string converted as NULL or 0

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
I am using MAC OSX YOSEMITE

Source JSON lifeData.json
        {"schema":{"vendor":"com.bd.snowplow","name":"in_life","format":"jsonschema","version":"1-0-2"},"data":{"step":0,"info_userId":"53493764","info_campaignCity":"","info_self_currentAge":45,"info_self_gender":"male","info_self_retirementAge":60,"info_self_married":false,"info_self_lifeExpectancy":0,"info_dependantChildren":0,"info_dependantAdults":0,"info_spouse_working":true,"info_spouse_currentAge":33,"info_spouse_retirementAge":60,"info_spouse_monthlyIncome":0,"info_spouse_incomeInflation":5,"info_spouse_lifeExpectancy":0,"info_finances_sumInsured":0,"info_finances_expectedReturns":6,"info_finances_loanAmount":0,"info_finances_liquidateSavings":true,"info_finances_savingsAmount":0,"info_finances_monthlyExpense":0,"info_finances_expenseInflation":6,"info_finances_expenseReduction":10,"info_finances_monthlyIncome":0,"info_finances_incomeInflation":5,"computed_results_A":"","computed_results_B":null,"computed_results_C":null,"computed_results_D":null,"uid_epoch":"53493764_1466504541604","state":"init","campaign_id":"","campaign_link":"","tool_version":"20150701-lfi-v1"},"hierarchy":{"rootId":"94583157-af34-4ecb-8024-b9af7c9e54fa","rootTstamp":"2016-06-21 10:22:24.000","refRoot":"events","refTree":["events","in_life"],"refParent":"events"}}

Schema JSON lifeSchema.json
        {
            "name": "computed_results_A",
            "type": "float",
            "mode": "nullable"
        }

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the JSON file as a one column CSV file.

```
bq load --field_delimiter='|' proj:set.table file.json json:string
```

Once the file is loaded into BigQuery, you can use JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR or a JavaScript UDF to parse the JSON with total freedom.